# SharePoint 2010 - Custom Property can't be accessed in VBA for brand new files

Tags: 2010, vba, custom-properties

I have a Document Library in SharePoint 2010 which will be used to receive Excel files via email.  I have created a column/property called "Status".  The default value for this is "New".

I email an excel spreadsheet to this Document Library.  It correctly shows that my "Status" property is set to "New" on my file.

I am writing VBA code in Microsoft Access to index and manipulate files on this SharePoint site.  When I attempt to check the value of that "Status" property for untouched files in the library, I get an error "The property "Status" does not exist in the collection".

If I go back to SharePoint, and click "Edit Properties" for that new file, save those properties (with or without changing them), then my VBA code works fine and I can view the "Status" property of that file.

So for some reason, these newly received files in SharePoint, while being displayed correctly, are not fully initializing that custom property.

Any ideas?  I am open for automated solutions from SP or VB.

Comment: VBA against SP ? You must be really brave :-D